# Sha256 returning incorrect hash values?

Tags: python, linux, bitcoin

I'm trying to hash a bitcoin private key to get the checksum, and two different libraries in python (hashlib + pycrypto) are returning the same incorrect result (after just 1 hash).

In linux terminal, I get the correct hash result with the line:

```
echo -n 8018ac3e7343f016890c510e93f935261169d9e3f565436429830faf0934f4f8e4 | xxd -r -p | sha256sum -b
result: cd358f378809b3043ded3782d849fbad70f92a2dadefafd985d9aef443752e57
```

However, hashlib, pycrypto, and an online SHA2 hash tool return the value:

```
5d6dce0f36a50abe51ee435ac11dac05f7879c1cd1ca5bc7aae706e5a3776d4a
```

I'm not sure why they are returning different values.

Here are two WIF-keys generated from them, the top one using the command line function, the second using python; the second one is invalid (not accepted by wallet softwares).

```
5J19pGYtJzuS7VoAQjxDjUGgWXSNqj18GWSWvFVqJzQqGtxZf2V
5J19pGYtJzuS7VoAQjxDjUGgWXSNqj18GWSWvFVqJzQqGvDc8hm
```

Comment: The Python libraries are not returning the wrong values. Show us your code and we may be able to tell you why you're having trouble. (I'll guess it has something to do with the common unicode/string confusion in Python 2.)

Comment: I think the problem is because `xxd -r -p`. If you try `echo -n 8018ac3e7343f016890c510e93f935261169d9e3f565436429830faf0934f4f8e4 | sha256sum -b` you'll also get the *incorrect hash values*. However I don't know what `xxd` does, but did you pass the result of `xxd` to Python `sha256` or just the string?

Comment: @KevinGuan `xxd -r -p` is "reverse hexdump", i.e. it should convert the hex back into binary.

Comment: @melpomene: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Oh thanks, just like said in [Simon Kirsten's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37758233/5299236).

Answer (score 2):

```
import hashlib

print(
    hashlib.sha256("8018ac3e7343f016890c510e93f935261169d9e3f565436429830faf0934f4f8e4").hexdigest()
)

print(
    hashlib.sha256("8018ac3e7343f016890c510e93f935261169d9e3f565436429830faf0934f4f8e4".decode("hex")).hexdigest()
)
```

Notice the difference:

The first code hashes the hex string.

The second hashes the byte string wich is returned by the hex decode.